# Convert variable arguments in C stdcall interface method to Delphi

Tags: delphi, winapi, com

I am converting the [ICallFrame](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/callobj/nf-callobj-icallframe-invoke) interface to Delphi and I am not sure how to handle the [ICallFrame::Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/callobj/nf-callobj-icallframe-invoke) method.

This is the definition:

```
HRESULT Invoke(
  void *pvReceiver,
  ...  
);
```

Per documentation the [varargs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Procedures_and_Functions_(Delphi)) directive works only with external routines and only with the cdecl calling convention.

It's a bit strange as Invoke is declared with `STDMETHODCALLTYPE` thus `__stdcall`, which is a callee-clean convention. But a variadic function cannot be callee-clean since the callee does not know how many parameters were passed.
Is there some kind of compiler magic if you do this with Visual Studio?

Even if compiler magic uses cdecl, the Delphi compiler doesn't accept this (because it's not external) `E2070 Unknown directive: 'varargs'`

```
ICallFrame = interface(IUnknown)
  ['{D573B4B0-894E-11d2-B8B6-00C04FB9618A}']
  // other methods left out
  function Invoke(pvReceiver: PVOID): HRESULT; cdecl; varargs;
end;
```

**Based on Rudy's answer it seems this could work:**

```
type
    TfnInvoke = function(this: Pointer; pvReceiver: Pointer): HRESULT; cdecl varargs;

implementation 

function GetInterfaceMethod(const intf; methodIndex: dword) : pointer;
begin
  Result := Pointer(pointer(dword_ptr(pointer(intf)^) + methodIndex * SizeOf(Pointer))^);
end;
...
var
  Invoker: TfnInvoke;
  ...
  // Don't forget IUnknown methods when counting!
  Invoker := GetInterfaceMethod(myIntf, 21);
  Invoker(myIntf, FObject, 11, 17.3);
```

I will test with this and report back...
EDIT: tested and works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Stdcall` cannot use variable arguments. Any C or C++ function taking variable arguments must be `__cdecl`, because only in that calling convention, the caller (code), which knows how many parameters were passed, cleans up the stack. Even if the default calling convention is `stdcall`, var args functions will be `cdecl`.

Delphi can not *generate* functions like that, but it can *consume existing external* C functions (in a DLL or .obj file) using the `varargs` directive.

So a C (or C++) function like

```
HRESULT Invoke(void *pvReceiver, ...);
```

should be converted as:

```
function Invoke(pvReceiver: Pointer); cdecl; varargs;
```

*Note that you leave out the `...` part in the Delphi declaration. It is assumed when you use the `varargs` directive.*

And that allows you to use it in Delphi like in C or C++:

```
Invoke(someReceiver, 17, 1.456);
```

---

Another example: for instance the well known C function `printf()`:

```
int printf(const char *format, ...);
```

is declared as

```
function printf(format: PAnsiChar {args}): Integer; cdecl; varargs;
```

in *System.Win.Crtl.pas*.

#### Update

This seems to be a method of an interface.

Not sure if that works, but I would try:

```
type
  TInvoke = function(Intf: IInterface; pvReceiver: Pointer): HRESULT; cdecl varargs; 
  // No semicolon between cdecl and varargs.
```

and use it as:

```
MyResult := TInvoke(@myIntf.Invoke)(myIntf, someReceiver, 11, 17.3);
```

This method may have been declared as `__stdcall` (through the `STDMETHODCALLTYPE` macro), but even then, if it is variadic, the (VC++) compiler will generate `__cdecl`, as Remy Lebeau found [in Raymond Chen's blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131128-00/?p=2543).

Comment: Seems that using `function Invoke(pvReceiver: Pointer): HRESULT; cdecl; varargs;` is not possible in an *interface* method (E2070 Unknown directive: 'varargs')

Comment: @Remko: then just omit the `varargs` part. Declare a global function: `function Invoke(Intf: IInterface; pvReceiver: Pointer); cdecl; varargs;` and cast the interface method to it, passing the interface as first argument. I did not try this, but that would be my first guess for a workaround.

Comment: Unfortunately this: ` type TfnInvoke = function(this: Pointer; pvReceiver: Pointer): HRESULT; cdecl; varargs;` doesn't make my compiler happy

Comment: @Remko: But this should work (no `;` between cdecl and varargs): `type TfnInvoke = function(this, pvReceiver: Pointer): HRESULT; cdecl varargs;`. It works in Delphi Tokyo.

Comment: If you look at the actual SDK declaration of `ICallFrame::Invoke()` in `callobj.h`, it is declared with `STDMETHODCALLTYPE`, which resolves to `__stdcall`. So I don't see how it is possible for `varargs` to ever work with this interface. In general, `varargs` is not compatible with COM at all, so I don't know what the designer of `ICallFrame` was thinking

Comment: @Remy: it gets weirder and weirderer. And it is meant to manipulate (stack) call frames. Weeeird.

Comment: Agreed @RudyVelthuis I didn't see how you could combine varargs and stdcall either. So best guess is the compiler will use cdecl and I think your suggest to cast could work (see my edit).

Comment: [If you try to declare a variadic function with an incompatible calling convention, the compiler secretly converts it to cdecl](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131128-00/?p=2543)

Comment: Upon re-reading the blog article that @RemyLebeau found it states: The Microsoft Visual Studio C/C++ compiler resolves this conflict by silently converting the calling convention to __cdecl, which is the only supported variadic calling convention for functions that do **not** take a hidden this parameter. That is confusing because I don't see how you could this with stdcall even if there **is** a hidden this parameter...

Comment: The fact is, `stdcall` simply doesn't support varidic parameters, period. Only `cdecl` does. So if the compiler sees `...` at the end of the argument list, it forces the calling convention to `cdecl`. Ignore the part about the `this` parameter, it is not relevant

Comment: Odly enough, if I don;t pass any variadic arguments both stdcall and cdecl appear to work fine (method is invoked)

Comment: `stdcall` and `cdecl` pass parameter values the same way, but they CLEAN UP the parameters in different ways. So it is important that you use the correct calling convention or you will corrupt the call stack.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180232/discussion-between-remko-and-remy-lebeau).

Comment: @Remko: please read the relevant part of my article: http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html#varargs